# How many countries did Lord Buddha travel?

Tags: the-buddha

While reading about Lord Buddha I found that he traveled to some other countries. But I couldn't find exactly how many countries. Does anyone know the answer for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Solosmasthana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solosmasthana) are 16 sacred places in Sri Lanka, that Gautama Buddha is said to have visited. Buddha is said to have visited the country three times and on one occasion, the  footprint of the Buddha was placed symbolizing the Buddha's presence. The sacred left footprint is said to be imprinted by Buddha on his third visit to Sri Lanka at the apex of the Sri Pada Mountain. There are two other places that the Buddha is said to have visited and placed the sacred footprint. One is in Thailand, and the other is at [Sunaparanta](http://www.tamroiphrabuddhabat.com/chaiwat/myanmar/2553/January/Buddha%20Visit%20to%20Shwesettaw.pdf) – the present day Saudi Arabia, & at the Kaabah.

Comment: What is your source about the Buddha visiting present-day Saudi Arabia? It doesn't sound very likely, and the documents you linked don't mention it either.

Comment: It is said that Buddha came three times to Lankapura from Janbudveepa (Mahavamsa Commentaries written by Bhikku Mahanama). This was written  after 600 years of Buddha’s parinirvana.  The footprint that is left by the Buddha @ Sri Pada (Adam's Peak) during the third & final visit to Sri Lanka, is said to be identical to that of the Kaabah, Mecca. The Muslims believe that it is the footprint of Prophet Hazrat Adam. The footprint in Sri Pada is there for everyone to see, but no one will ever get to compare and contrast the two footprints, as the precinct of Kaabah is out of bounds to everyone.

Comment: It is possible that Buddha visited Saudi Arabia but wasn’t Jambudvipa earth and other three continents are invisible to people who doesn’t have the divine eye?

Answer (score 1):

i tried to look for document i read a few years back but no luck. Maybe someone saw the same document as i did and has a better luck finding it.  Someone have compiled a list of places mentioned in the beginning of suttas to map out Buddha's where about at each raining season.  He stayed in Jettawana grove the longest for 20 years, next was monastery (i dont remember the name) built by lady Visaka for 10 years, 5 years or less in other places such as one built by his physician Jivaka (i believe it was mango grove), Bamboo groove (Veluvana) etc.  If you go by the record in these sutta, Buddha did not travel beyond what currently are India and Napal.

Comment: Maybe just over what is currently the border with [Nepal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakya), too?

Comment: oh yes, and Lumbini, Nepal.

Comment: During the rains retreat (vassa), Buddha generally stayed in one place. See [**HERE**](http://www.buddhanet.net/bud_lt17.htm)  for a detailed description of these places.

Comment: FYI, I know Lord Buddha Visited Sri Lanka 3 Times..

Comment: @RANSARA009 I suppose that 'knowledge' is based on Sri Lanka's [Mahavamsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahavamsa), and/or on its precursor the [Dipavamsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipavamsa).

Answer (score 0):

Load budhdha was born in jambudeepa in india(nepal). Srilanka is not budhdha's born contry. jambudeepa is not ancient srilanka. some one early mentioned  "janbudeepa is ancient sri lanka " this details are not correct. Its completly wrong so used refferences also wrong.that refferences were writen by some crazy person. If this writer's age is 75y he is think only his experience he was wrote books what he think about budhda it is not through and there is no other histrorical sourse say like this. But sri lanka has 2500 years histrorical books so eny one can understand read with mahawanshaya and thripitakaya. Gawthama budhda was born in India(nepal ) not sri lanka.thats the historical through.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Lord Buddha visiting countries out of India, there are no credible evidence to show that he left the Ganges Plains during his lifetime. He mostly travelled on foot. The stories of him miraculously flying or appearing in Sri Lanka, Thailand, Cambodia or otherwise were mere stories generated by Buddhist missionaries working towards establishing the religion in those countries after the death of Lord Buddha. This was done in order to invoke religious legitimacy by making Buddhism relate to the inhabitants of those lands. It worked well I must say its a smart missionary tactic.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't disparage or "attack" other schools of Buddhism -- it isn't necessary, instead it's enough to explain what your own view of a topic is.

Comment: Noted with thanks. I was not trying to attack a sect trying to mislead and edit Buddhist history, I was trying to show that they were wrong since the topic is in discussion in the comments below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Buddha traveled other than by foot. Hard to explain to those who are restricted to a sentient world. Best way to explain is teleportation through the mind. The Buddha is an enlightened person whose mind has become one with the cosmos. He sees and feels the universe. In Buddhist literature, it is known that the Buddha visited other domains or realms. He is even said to have visited his mother and preached the dhamma. Travelling on foot is the sentient perception, which cannot see how the Buddha traveled through teleportation. For this reason, historians and observers around him would have never seen or known where he went in this form of travel, because all they would know is him in deep meditation. That they confirm and mention that between 2 and 4 am he preached to the devas (gods). The historic record in Sri Lanka of Buddha's visits is similar to teleportation, which in Sanskrit was called Iridi.

Answer (score -2):

India is not the land of lord buddha. The british conquers changed and misunderstood the history of india and sri lanka. Lord Buddha born in JAMBUDEEPA. Jambudeepa is ancient sri lanka. A part of ancient sri lanka was known as Jambudeepa. Sri lanka is the lowest gravity country in the world where the Lord Buddha born. India was never known as Jambudeepa. Indian history has no records of buddha. But Sri lanka has many records. Buddha never visited any country. Lord Buddha travelled only in the island of ancient sri lanka. (helabima). Mahawansa is about the histroy of ancient sri lanka. Dambadiva and Jambudeepa refer to sri lanka. But people misunderstood it.

References:

- [Gautama Buddha was born in Hela Bima](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2m3yxwhl8zgaS1EZmx3b2VteTQ/view)
- [Gautama Buddha was born in Hela Bima (Volume II)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2m3yxwhl8zgMk9kSFFnVkJVM0k/view)

Comment: Could you share citations?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2m3yxwhl8zgaS1EZmx3b2VteTQ/view

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2m3yxwhl8zgMk9kSFFnVkJVM0k/view